# I am generating letter from visualforce page in french-

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce-id, dynamic-visualforce

I am generating letter from visualforce page in french

à is changing into the character of Ã  .

like the same way two to three characters are getting changed while generating the letter .can some body explain why it is changing how we can solve this issue?

after using the code that codes it is taking as Ã for(à)

Comment: After using the code also it is taking the same

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: When you say you generate a letter, I assume you create an email and send that out. You then see the wrong characters in the mail client on the receiving end, is this correct? In such a scenario there are many places where stuff can go wrong. You need to ensure that you always use the proper encoding, e.g. UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1, during creation and transfer of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ASCI character - `&#224;`

There is a full list here - http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: i tried in pdf it is getting same but in letter generation it is changing

Comment: still it is taking as Ã.i have used the same code